# Button Background not applying to paging buttons

Tags: 2013, css, branding, theme

I've noticed when using the SharePoint Color Palette tool, that when I change the Button Background value the preview shows that the paging buttons will change with this color.  However when I apply the theme (.spcolor file) to my site, the button background for the paging buttons stay white.  Hover background works as expected, but the non-hover value seems not to be applied.

Anyone have a similar experience?  Any way around this without writing some CSS?